# Erro usando uma view para dois controllers

Tags: angularjs, html5

Eu tenho um controller para adicionar um objeto e ela utiliza a view. **addObjeto.html**

Eu tenho outro controller que é para editar esse objeto, e ao acessá-lo ele preenche toda a view **addObjeto.html**.

O que iria ser diferente seria só o **botão de submit** que a depender iria ser **"Editar"** ou **"Adicionar"**

Criei uma variável no controller chamada **`$rootScope.buttonCtrl`**.

Em que acessar o `addObjetoCtrl` a variável tinha valor **`$rootScope.buttonCtrl = true;`**

E em que acessar o `editObjetoCtrl` a variável tinha valor **`$rootScope.buttonCtrl = false;`**

E na view eu tenho

```
<button type="button" ng-click="addTarefa()" ng-show="buttonCtrl" 
        class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="tarefa.titulo == null || 
        tarefa.descricao == null || cl.classe==null">
    Cadastrar
</button>

<button type="button" ng-click="editarTarefa()" ng-show="buttonCtrl == false" 
        class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="tarefa.titulo == null || 
        tarefa.descricao==null || cl.classe==null ">
    Editar
</button>
```

Porém o que acontece é que na **view** o valor de **buttonCtrl** está sendo sempre **`true`**, logo, somente o botão "Cadastrar" está aparecendo. O que pode ser?

Comment: Você inicializou sua variável como "false"? Você entrou na pagina de Editar e nem assim aparece?

Comment: Você consegue printar na tela o valor de `buttonCtrl` e conferir se ele está realmente correto nas duas chamadas?

Answer (score 0):

> Criei uma variável no controller chamada `$rootScope.buttonCtrl`

Nop, você criou uma variável no escopo-raiz (`$rootScope`). Dois problemas:

- Este escopo não pertence ao *controller* (o escopo do controller
  herda de `$rootScope`);
- A criação de variáveis no `$rootScope` é considerada [uma prática ruim](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/vYLM1hUc6yE).

Entre outras possíveis causas, seu problema pode ser o resultado de um escopo isolado.

O exemplo funcional abaixo ilustra a utilização de escopos locais (`$scope`). Clique em <kbd>Executar</kbd> para vê-lo em ação:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('adicionarCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.titulo  = "Adicionar"; 
  $scope.buttonCtrl  = true; 
})
.controller('editarCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.titulo  = "Editar"; 
  $scope.buttonCtrl = false; 
})
;
```

```css
.painel
{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:10px 5px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tpl.html">
    {{titulo}}
    
    <button type="button" ng-click="addTarefa()" ng-show="buttonCtrl" class="btn btn-default">
        Cadastrar
    </button>

    <button type="button" ng-click="editarTarefa()" ng-show="!buttonCtrl" class="btn btn-default">
        Editar
    </button>
  </script>

  <div ng-include="'tpl.html'" ng-controller='adicionarCtrl'></div>
  <div ng-include="'tpl.html'" ng-controller='editarCtrl'></div>
</div>
```